# connect with postgresql and use query

Tags: c#, postgresql

I want to connect to a postgresql database and use an insert query.
I have done some research but i have no clue what i am doing.
So i don't even know if i am connected with the postgresql.

here is my code:

```
String conn = ("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User id=*******;Password=***;Database=database1;");
try
{
    NpgsqlConnection objConn = new NpgsqlConnection(conn);
    objConn.Open();
    string strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO weather (date, city, temp_hi, temp_lo) VALUES ('1994-11-29', 'Hayward', 54, 37);";
    NpgsqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, objConn);

    objConn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: `I have done some research but i have no clue what i am doing` - do you have a clue whether you are getting an exception when you run this code?

Comment: No I dont get any exception.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have used the awnser below and now i get this 
The type or namespace name 'NpgSqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
String conn = ("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User id=*******;Password=***;Database=database1;");
            try
            {
                NpgsqlConnection objConn = new NpgsqlConnection(conn);
                objConn.Open();
                string strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO weather (date, city, temp_hi, temp_lo) VALUES ('1994-11-29', 'Hayward', 54, 37);";

               NpgSqlCommand cmd=new NpgSqlCommand(strSelectCmd,objConn);
               cmd.ExcuteNonquery();

               objConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
     }
```

Comment: I am getting this error: The type or namespace name 'NpgSqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)